# Wordpress & Woocommerce Product SKU on Single Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i have a woo commerce website and i'm trying to get the Product SKU displaying on the single product page,

i have different SKU for Variable Products.

Answer (score 0):

`$product->sku;`

This will display Your product sku.

Comment: Where are you displaying it??

Comment: short-descriptions.php

<?php echo $_product->sku; ?>

Comment: global $product;
echo  $product->sku ;

Comment: this will display your product sku on short-description.php also

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in function.php file .

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wdm_show_sku', 5 );
function wdm_show_sku(){
global $product;
echo $product->get_sku();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but faced the same problem and the following worked for me.

The OP mentioned that he wishes to display SKU for variable products on the single product page which means he probably needs for the SKU to be updated whenever a variation is chosen.

As mentioned in this post https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15445

> the javascript code which updates the SKU requires some specific classnames for the SKU display for it to know what to update.

However it looks like the hook `$product->sku;` doesn't always include the required classes so it might be needed to add them manually.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'vtk_show_sku', 5);
  function vtk_show_sku(){
    global $product;
      echo '<div class="product_meta">SKU:<span class="sku">' . $product->get_sku(). '</span></div>';
}
```